# How can I get the default value of a ListPreference as defined in the XML?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, listpreference

How I can programmatically get the default value of a `ListPreference` as it have defined in the XML?

Here is the snippet of my `ListPreference`:

```
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="60"
        android:entries="@array/interval_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/interval_values"
        android:key="interval"
        android:summary="@string/interval_summary"
        android:title="@string/interval_title" />
```

I have been through the docs but I have not found a way to get this. Maybe I have overlooked it.

Comment: Are you using Fragment or not?

Comment: I'm using a `PreferenceActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PreferenceActivity (deprecated with Fragment), try:

```
ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) this.findPreference(this.getString(R.string.my_key));
lp.getValue();
```

Where **my_key** is the key value assigned to this ListPreference. Note: This value is defined in `strings.xml`. If you have hard-coded your key with a literal string, then substitute **my_key** with whichever string you've given for the `android:key` tag. So, in your case, the codes will be:

```
ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) this.findPreference("interval");
lp.getValue();
```

Comment: current value is NOT default value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to initially set the default value or reset it to default? Regardless have a look at:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.your_pref_xml, false);
```

and the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: get. Only get default